# multi-thread image generation python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, thread-safety

For a ML/DL project I have a set of features which I want to convert to image.

The data format looks like

```
Group Name Feat X Feat y .... Feat z
1     A.   
1.    B.
1.    C.   
2.    D
2.    A.
2.    E
```

Where feature X to Z is a ordered list of 60 numbers. The goal is to plot them using 1 to 60 as X axis and the feature value as Y as a line grouped by Name for each group.
So the group 1 figure would have 3 lines (A,B,C).

This is the function I have so far where subs is a pandas dataframe after groupby by ['Group']

```
ids = list(subs['Group'])[0]
subs.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
subs = subs.T
fig=subs.plot(figsize=(32,32), legend=False).get_figure()
plt.axis('off')
# convert figure to PIL image
buf = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(buf,  bbox_inches='tight')
buf.seek(0)
img = Image.open(buf).convert('LA')
img.save("{}/{}.png".format(path, ids),"PNG", optimize=True,quality=50)
buf.close()
plt.close()
```

This is applied with df.groupby['Group'].apply(lambda x: data2img(x, img_path)).

The code works  and generate the correct figure but I have millions of groups and takes forever.

My go-to for this kind of things is usually dask but when I did use it it raised a safety issue because matplotlib is not thread safe.
Any idea on how to circumvent this issue/other ideas on how to speed up image generation?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not replicable but try something like:

```
import concurrent.futures
groups = list(df.groupby("Group").groups.keys())
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as ex:
    ex.map(your_func, groups)
```

where `your_func` will be a function similar to the lambda function you got.